# Changing the appearance of form with code

Tags: delphi

You can change the appearance of your form by selecting the "Project" tab, then "Options", then "Appearance".
Is there any way that I can change this with code, while the program is running? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add/select the required styles from "Appearance" and get those selected styles from `TStyleManager.StyleNames`. Follow [this brief tutorial](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781785287428/1/ch01lvl1sec10/changing-the-style-of-your-vcl-application-at-runtime) which shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Muminjon, the tutorial really helped a lot. The essentials seem to be adding "Vcl.Themes" and "Vcl.Styles" in uses, and typing TStyleManager.SetStyle("...") where needed.